# Running GL applications through UTM: GLX: Failed to create context: GLXBadFBConfig

Tags: apple-silicon, virtualization

I have a Mac with OSX installed, and I'm trying to run a virtual machine with Debian. I am using [`utm`](https://mac.getutm.app/) to virtualize Debian with the arm64 arch. When I run `kitty`, a graphical Linux terminal with 3D-acceleration, I'm getting

```
[glfw error 65543]: GLX: Failed to create context: GLXBadFBConfig
Failed to create GLFW temp window! This usually happens because of old/broken OpenGL drivers. kitty requires working OpenGL 3.3 drivers.
```

How can I resolve this error? I can get around this error with

```
LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=true kitty
```

But, I want hardware acceleration which `utm` claims to support. If I look at my video device with `lspci`, I see it's

```
00:02.0 Display controller: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio GPU (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### OpenGL is not supported

> When I run `kitty`, a graphical Linux terminal with 3D-acceleration…

3D acceleration requires a GPU.  The error message “*This usually happens because of old/broken OpenGL drivers*” also points to this; the drivers are “broken” because there’s no GPU to talk to because…

**UTM lacks the support for GPU emulation.**

Per the [front page of the UTM website](https://mac.getutm.app/), it specifically states that it doesn’t support this feature (see below).  Granted, the information is under the heading concerning games, but OpenGL is something used *extensively* for gaming.

> **Can I run games?**
>
> No, probably not. UTM does not currently support GPU emulation/virtualization on Windows and therefore lacks support for 3D acceleration (e.g. OpenGL and DirectX). **There is experimental support for hardware OpenGL acceleration on Linux through Virgl**.

<sup>Emphasis Mine</sup>

As for Linux, the support is only *experimental* and looks to be a port of some kind from/supported on QEMU.  Take that to mean that in UTM’s current state,  it’s not currently supported.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug related to OpenGL 3.3 specifically.

https://github.com/utmapp/UTM/issues/4285